# Is it necessary to ensure deep copy for array assignment in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am making a new application for my first-ever developer intern and I want to know if it is necessary for me to ensure deep copy in mongoose.

```
// @route    PUT api/users/:userid
// @desc     edit user
// @access   super admin
router.put('/:userid', auth, isSuperAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findById(req.params.userid);

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'User does not exist' }] });
    }

    user.access = req.body.access;  

    await user.save();

    res.json({ msg: 'Successfully edited' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});
```

For example, in the code, I assign an array of ObjectIds that are accessible by a user (user.access = req.body.access). However, I am not sure if I should use a spread operator or JSON.parse with stringify to ensure a deep copy before the assignment or did the mongoose already has some hidden features that get the job done for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Cloning

If you are messing with the response and don't want any trouble then creating a deep Clone of response is a good idea.

for that methods like `toObject()` or `toJSON()` are attached to query response wich gives deeply cloned copy of response.

definitely they are doing same JSON.stringify and JSON.parse internally.

```
let response = await User.findById(req.params.userid);
let user = response.toJSON();
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

## spread operator

if you want to create first level copy then it will work, and you have to work around for nested objects.

hence JSON.stringify and parsing is very heavy operation spread operator is a lot faster way of creating copies.

## Ex

```
// Will work fine with high performance
var test = { a:1, b:2, c:3};
var clone = { ...test };

// Will mess
var test = { a : {b : 0, c : 0}, b: 3 };
var clone = { ...test }

this will work for property `b` but not for nested object. what you can do here is.

var clone = { ...test, a: ...test.a };

// can solve your problem without losing performance.
```